# preg_replace whole words or between punctuation

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to expand on a question I asked earlier.  I would like to use preg_replace to switch whole words or words butted up to certain punctuation or symbols such as 
`\s\,\:\-\%\(\)\*\&\$\#\!\@\"\;`
Currently, I'm using something like this,

```
$_SESSION['ABBREV']['GENERAL']['SEARCH'][] = '/(?<=\s|^)' . preg_quote($row['word'], '/') . '(?=\s|$)/i';
$_SESSION['ABBREV']['GENERAL']['REPLACE'][] = ucwords($row['abbrev']);

$word   = $_SESSION['ABBREV']['GENERAL']['SEARCH'];  --array that holds whole words
$abbrev = $_SESSION['ABBREV']['GENERAL']['REPLACE']; --array that stores abbreviations
$string = 'James Laughlin Music Center, Chatham University';

$new_word = = preg_replace($word, $abbrev, $string);
```

I would like it to come out as James Laughlin Music Cntr., Chatham University where Cntr. is an abbreviation for center.  I would also like it if for some reason it was James Laughlin Music,Center Hall Chatham University to come out James Laughlin Music,Cntr. Hall Chatham University. I'm not sure if I'm explaining it well.

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundaries:

```
'/\b' . preg_quote($row['word'], '/') . '\b/i'
```